# Need help: seaching corporate email for messages sent to specific domains

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook

Management has determined that there is a need to search all 1500+ users Outlook and see who has been sending email to the competition.  Does anybody know a tool/script/package that will enable us to search users pst files and see who has been corresponding with the enemy?

Comment: Wow. POP3 env? Exchange?

Comment: Shocking, isn't it. I don't envy the poster at all. I'm fairly certain he's stuck buying dodgy third-party software to handle this, but since I've never used any I'm not going to speak to it.

Comment: @mathewC Given hes talking about Outlook I would say its an exchange environment.  People tend to use the words outlook and exchange interchangeably despite being very different areas

Comment: Do you know if they want to see past correspondence, or current. You might be able to watch traffic instead of going though sheetpiles of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Sherpa Software's products; they have some automated tools that can inventory and search PSTs on network shares or individual workstations.

Comment: Downloading a trial, this sounds like exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

When I've had to do this in the past, I used [Discovery Attender](http://www.sherpasoftware.com/microsoft-exchange-products/discovery-attender.shtml).  I'm assuming you have an Exchange server.  They also have an option for [Lotus Notes](http://www.sherpasoftware.com/lotus-notes-products/discovery-attender.shtml).

Answer (score 1):

If it's happened recently, you could try using the Message Tracking tool in ESM. Just put in your exchange server(s) and the domain that you want to look for. Might give you clues so you don't have to search all 1500+ users' pst files.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to implement an email archiving solution. Red Gate software has one (disclaimer: I've received money from them for writing articles in a magazine they publish), but Global Relay is a solid service that you can outsource it to, if you don't have the high availability stuff it requires.

Comment: I'll definitely check them out.

Answer (score 0):

An Exchange environment but with PST files?  You might be able to exmerge them into a database, which will at least take some of the pain away.

Comment: That's one of the options that we thought of, just trying to see what other people might have encountered